# Login failed for user even though it has read access

Tags: sql-server-2008, security, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint server which is using service account "spsharepoint".

For some reason this user has started giving '**Login failed for user DOMAIN\spsharepoint**' when I checked SQL Server logs. Turns out it is trying to access 'master' database on which it doesn't have access so the error.

I gave read only access to this user on master database but error is still coming. What could be the issue and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify if your user has permision to connect to database Engine. 
Right click on Logins -> Properties -> Status.

Or grant CONNECT for user.

```
CREATE LOGIN [mydomain\mygroup] FROM WINDOWS;
GRANT CONNECT SQL TO [mydomain\mygroup]
```

Answer (score 1):

View the default database in user's properties, may be it is master, if so, then change it

Answer (score 1):

One option is create login with default database option and add role member to login user in database

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE LOGIN [CUREMD\NewLogin] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[AdventureWorks]
GO

USE [AdventureWorks]--- Change DB name to Sharepoint DB Name
GO

CREATE USER [CUREMD\NewLogin] FOR LOGIN [CUREMD\NewLogin]
GO

USE [AdventureWorks]   --- Change DB name to Sharepoint DB Name
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'CUREMD\NewLogin' -- add role according to requirement.
GO
```